# Why runs into NullpointerException when calling getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE)

Tags: java, android, android-context

I run into the `NullPointerException` while calling `getSystemService()`. I checked some posts before but can't figure out why it failed.

```
public class GetGyroInfo extends Service implements LocationListener{
    private float mLongAccl;
    private float mLatAccl;

    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 100; // 100 millisecond

    //Declaring a location manager
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private Location mLocation = null;

    private static final String TAG = "ADAS_GetGyroInfo";

    public void getLocation(Context context){

        //Note: getApplicationContext returns NULL inside this constructor. Reason not clear.

        //Create a registor for location updates
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)  getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
...
}
```

The above class is initialized in the following class:

```
    public class ABCService extends Service {

    ...
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        sendStatusBroadcast(true);

        //Registor location service.
        mgetGyroInfo = new GetGyroInfo();
        mgetGyroInfo.getLocation();
}
```

I tried the following code and it succeeds:

```
mgetGyroInfo.getLocation(getApplicationContext());
```

So my question is, why I have to pass the context from `ABCService` class to `GetGyroInfo`? Why can't I get the context inside `GetGyroInfo` itself?

Comment: `mgetGyroInfo = new GetGyroInfo();` -- **never** create an instance of an activity or service yourself.

Comment: To complete what @CommonsWare said, here is the most basic way to start a Service on Android.
First, create an intent :
    `Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class);`
Then start the service :
    `startService(intent);`

Comment: @Ephi, Thanks for the clarification. Obviously the code doesn't follow the way service class should be used.